# Lock / Monitor.Enter and deadlock scenario

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to debug some old code in a product running on a Windows Embedded Compact 7 and .NET CF 3.5. I do suspect a deadlock scenario but can't figure out the reason. The originating code seems to be a class (code below) encapsulating a thread and an AutoResetEvent. It uses lock and Monitor.Enter to acquire lock for thread safety.

Is there something obvious in the following code potentially causing a deadlock that i would be missing?

```
//constructor
public SequentialThreadWorker(
        string threadName,
        ThreadPriority threadPriority)
    {
        _workerThread = new Thread(OnThreadStart)
        {
            Name = threadName,
            Priority = threadPriority,
            IsBackground = true
        };

        _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _actionsQueue = new Queue<Action>();

        _workerThread.Start();
    }

//external multi-threaded code can enqueue task using the following method
    public void Enqueue(Action action)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _actionsQueue.Enqueue(action);
            _waitHandle.Set();
        }
    }

//ThreadStart code depiling action from the queue action to execute
    private void OnThreadStart()
    {
        while (_run)
        {
            Action actionData = null;

            Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            try
            {
                if (_actionsQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    actionData = _actionsQueue.Dequeue();

                    if (_actionsQueue.Count > 0)
                        _waitHandle.Set();
                    else
                        _waitHandle.Reset();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //do log
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }

            if (actionData != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    actionData();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //do log
                }
            }
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

}